# Warning C4091: ' __declspec(dllexport)'

Tags: declspec

I have the following code where I am trying to export a function called "Interface_API" out of my dll.

```
#ifdef INTERFACEDLL_EXPORTS
#define UserApp_API __declspec(dllexport);
#else
#define UserApp_API __declspec(dllimport);
#endif

UserApp_API int Interface_API(int *, int *, int *);
```

When I compile this code it gives the following warning and the function is not getting exported.

```
warning C4091: ' __declspec(dllexport)' : ignored on left of 'int' when no variable is declared
```

When I change the declaration as given below I don't get the warning and it exports properly.

```
__declspec(dllexport) int Interface_API(int *, int *, int *);
```

I am little confused because I have used it in different dll and it works fine. Any clue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#define UserApp_API __declspec(dllimport);
                                         ^ Semicolon.
```

Comment: for clarity semicolon should be removed in the #define

Comment: Thank you! That's maddening! The error message doesn't make sense.